# How to achieve a Menu with only Image in SwiftUI for macos?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, menu

## What I'm doing

I'm coding a mac App in SwiftUI, where swift is in version of 5.7.2.

## What I want to do

Click a image button, and display a drop-down menu.

## My question

The following is my code, and there is always a down arrow on the right of the button.
I wonder how to remove the default down arrow, and only leave an "ellipsis" image button.

## My code

```
Menu {
    Text("Menu Item 1")
    Text("Menu Item 2")
    Text("Menu Item 3")
} label:{
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
}
```

## Menu

It always has a down arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Open Menu on click

Unfortunately, directly creating a menu with only an image in SwiftUI for macOS isn't possible due to platform limitations. However, there are workarounds you can use to achieve a similar effect:

1. Button with Image:
   Create a Button with an Image as its label.
   Use the menuStyle(.borderlessButton) to remove the default button borders.
   Optionally, you can adjust the image size and background color for a cleaner look.
2. Menu with Hidden Text Label:
   Create a Menu and define its items using Button.
   Inside each Button, use an Image as its label.
   Add a hidden text label with the actual functionality description using .hidden().
   This way, the user sees only the image on the menu, but the underlying functionality remains accessible.
3. Custom Menu Style (Ventura 13.3.1+):
   This approach requires macOS Ventura 13.3.1 or later.
   Define a custom MenuStyle that displays your image label on macOS but hides it on other platforms.
   This method offers more flexibility but requires deeper understanding of SwiftUI internals.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! However, the above code reports error, where `configuration` doesn't has the `trigger` function